# Check if number is divisible by 9 without a simple modulo

Tags: java, division

Got the following assignment for school:

> To check if a given number is divisible by 9 you can try taking the sum of all seperate numbers from that number. When we have the result of that sum we can easily check if it's divisible by 9.
>
> Write a program that checks if a number is divisible by 9 using this given method. Make sure that all sums in between get written down as in the following example.

```
input 2656
19
10
1
no

input -9999542
47
11
2
no

input 91827
27
9
yes
```

I could use modulo operator in the first place, but since I'm being told to do it like that I have no idea how to work this out.

Does someone have any tips?

EDIT: not allowed to use strings or arrays.

Comment: I don't see where, in the assignment, it's being said that you can't use modulo. So, where's the problem?

Comment: @Tim what have you tried so far? It's your homework.. people will help you only if you try and you're stuck.

Comment: @JBNizet Well, repetitively using `n % 10` to check whether `n % 9 == 0` is a somewhat questionable procedure…  (@Tim: Hint: What would `n / 10` be?)

Comment: The tip is to add all digits. While you *can* use `%` to get each one, it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @5gon12eder: of course, it's stupid. But the goal here is to learn how to use loops, and maybe recursion. Not to design an optimal way of determining if a number is divisible by 9.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course, but I'm not sure whether the corrector will like to see that use of `%`.  (Maybe it wasn't “officially introduced” yet.)  Well, I don't know what he's supposed to learn, just thinking.  It's not my homework.

Comment: I could just do number%9 and see if it is different from 0 or not straight away. But the thing is that for example if the input is 2656, the digits have to be add up, so 2+6+5+6, but I have no idea how to do this when you do not know how many digits the number will have. We are not allowed to use arrays yet. Also, I don't get why ther's a need to display the 10 in the first example. It's 19 - 9, obviously.. At the end when I have added up all those digits I am allowed to use modulo.

Comment: the 10 in the first example is rather the summation of all digits of "19".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]), help = 0, sum= 0;

if (x < 0) {
    x *= -1;
}

do {
    while(x != 0) {
        help = x % 10;
        sum += help;
        x /= 10;
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

    if(sum >= 10) {
        x = sum;
        sum = 0;
    }

}while(x >= 10);

if(sum / 9 == 1) {
    System.out.println("yes");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum all the digits and then check if the sum is divisible by 9 . Use recursion repeat the logic. E.g.

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input1 = 2656;
        int input2 = -9999542;
        int input3 = 91827;
        System.out.println("\n" + "input " + input1);
        check(input1);
        System.out.println("\n" + "input " + input2);
        check(input2);
        System.out.println("\n" + "input " + input3);
        check(input3);

    }

    public static boolean check(int input) {
        int sum = calculateSum(input);
        System.out.println(sum);
        if (sum < 9) {
            System.out.println("no");
            return false;
        }

        if ((double) sum / 9 == 1.0) {
            System.out.println("yes");
            return true;
        }

        return check(sum);
    }

    private static int calculateSum(int digits)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        digits = digits < 0 ? -1 * digits : digits;
        while ( digits > 0 )
        {
            sum += digits % 10;
            digits /= 10;
        }

        return sum;
    }

}
```

output

```
input 2656
19
10
1
no

input -9999542
47
11
2
no

input 91827
27
9
yes
```

Comment: Edit: not allowed to use arrays and strings, that's the biggest problem I'm stuck with :(

Comment: @Tim i updated the answer to use no String and Array, but using % operator to calculate digit sum is ok?

Comment: Thanks. I saw Yoshi just added a simplified version of this using just 1 input, but yours will work too.